# Android - how to properly draw an arrow with Path?

Tags: android, path, ondraw

I'm trying to draw an arrow but I get a really strange result.
[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqjXY.jpg)  and the problem is pretty clear - the overlapping part.

```
int radius = 100;  //Radius of blue circle to the right
Path leftArrow = new Path();
Paint leftArrowPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

leftArrowPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
leftArrowPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.buttonText));
leftArrowPaint.setAlpha(80);
leftArrowPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
```

Within onDraw method:

```
//Start point
leftArrow.moveTo(touchX-(radius+5),  (int)touchY);
//Line to left
leftArrow.lineTo(touchX-(radius+60), (int)touchY);
//Line up
leftArrow.lineTo(touchX-(radius+30), (int)touchY-30);
//Move back to the middle
leftArrow.moveTo(touchX-(radius+60), (int)touchY);
//Line down
leftArrow.lineTo(touchX-(radius+30), (int)touchY+30);
canvas.drawPath(leftArrow, leftArrowPaint);
leftArrow.reset();
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I know it's too late for you, but I'm gonna answer anyway in case someone comes across the same problem.

You need to specify the Paint's Join property.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.Join.html

```
leftArrowPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.BEVEL);
```

You can also use `Paint.Join.ROUND`, depending on what looks better for you.

Comment: Better late than never, you just saved myself from searching for hours as I couldn't find out why the same is happening for me.You deserve a star :-)